How to change displayed size of newlines?
I am writing .md files in vim, and for formatting reasons I would like each 'paragraph' to be one line in the file. However, for readability reasons while writing, I would like to have a blank line visually inserted between each line of the file, to better delineate large chunks of text.
I have tried a number of things, including setting set listchars=eol:^M (or with a number of other newline representations), but so far none of them have worked. There might be a way to convert this answer regarding doubling the whitespace of tabs, but I don't have the knowledge to implement it.

Welcome to the site. Your question could be improved with a short sample of text and how you want it to look.

It sounds like you really want the wrap option, but it’s hard to tell. Please [edit] an example in as mentioned above
